# Will HTML elements have a load success promise?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-promise

While getting used to the concept of promises I have been wondering if elements like HTMLImageElement will have a native promise in future for a 'load' success or failure, similar to the 'load' event which already exists, but with the advantages of being able to be polled after loading?

https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/promises-guide#one-time-events

Comment: Are there plans for any native elements to have a Promise interface?

Comment: I am not sure, but looking around I have not found any mention. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the best use case for promises, but to me it sounds like something which would make a lot of sense - however maybe I am overlooking a reason why it isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Promises are definitly a good idea. The *problem* however is that the DOM has an event model and events and Promises don't really work well together. You can't have a promise for an *onclick* event for instance (well, you can, but what does it mean?) Some events, like *load*, may seem to make sense but what if you change the `src`? You'll get another *load* event!

Maybe someone is going to have a good idea how to unify these concepts. For now, I think we're stuck with writing code that interfaces between events and Promises.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and has helped clarify why promises are not a perfect fit for the use case I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Not as of HTML5.  But I like the concept.  I would love to see promise-events in HTML6.

The document you referenced is a guide for when to use promises.  So, if you are creating a custom object with events, you might consider implementing a promise interface for your one-time events.

You could easily implement a library to add promise events to DOM elements today.

```
function loadPromise(image) {
    if (image.src && image.complete) {
        if (image.naturalWidth > 0) {
            return Promise.resolve(image);
        }
        else {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("image failed loading"));
        }
    }
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        image.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
            resolve(image);
        }, false);
        image.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
            reject(new Error("image failed loading"));
        }, false);
        if (image.src) {
            // IE reports image.complete as false when there is an error
            var errTest = new Image();
            errTest.onerror = function(e) {
                reject(new Error("image failed loading"));
            };
            errTest.src = image.src;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made an attempt to add such a promise onto images myself, however the problem with an implementation added in JavaScript is the case where a resource had loaded before the JavaScript, meaning I needed messy extra code to force a reload to make sure the event had not been missed.

Comment: I added an implementation to my answer.  A reload shouldn't be necessary (except for IE).  If `image.src` is set and `image.complete` is true, you can check `naturalWidth` to see if it loaded or errored.  IE shows `image.complete` as false when there is an error, so you do have to rely on a reload to detect that case.